# Is every finite extension L/K separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to determine whether this statement is true or false. However I only understand that every finite extension of a finite field is separable from another solution. ([Every finite extension of a finite field is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260426/every-finite-extension-of-a-finite-field-is-separable))

So what difference is finite or not with regards to the finite extension being separable or not?

Thank you

Comment: The statement is false, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478135/give-3-examples-of-a-field-extensions-which-are-neither-normal-nor-separable). See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527972/give-an-example-of-a-finite-extension-of-fields-that-is-neither-separable-nor-no?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: A field extension $L/K$ is called finite when its degree is finite, that is, when the  dimension of $L$ as $K$-vector space is finite. This is always true if $L$ is a finite field, but for example $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ is also a finite extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that a finite field is *perfect*, but there are infinite fields that aren't.

The basic example is the following (in a sense it's the "only" example) : assume you have a field $K$ of characteristic $p$, and $a\in K$ has no $p$th root. Then $X^p - a$ is irreducible over $K$ (this is not immediate but follows with a bit of work).

However if you take a finite extension $L/K$ where it has a root $b$, then $X^p-a = (X-b)^p$, and so the extension isn't separable